# Simulink: Get Attribute in SimEvents

Tags: matlab, simulink, simevents

Recently, "get attribute" block has been obsoleted in SimEvents: https://se.mathworks.com/help/simevents/ref/getattributeobsolete.html

The question is: how can we get an attribute value in SimEvents (using Entity Generator)? I want to use the value for plotting or more importantly use in a Simulink function.

Answer (score 1):

Those blocks were obsoleted in about R2016a.

There's a section in the doc that discusses how to [Migrate Legacy SimEvent Models](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simevents/migrate-legacy-simevents-models.html).

Linked off that page is a list describing how to [Replace Old Blocks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simevents/ug/replace-old-blocks.html).

And specific to your question there is a page showing how to [Connect Port Signals](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simevents/ug/connect-signal-ports.html) directly, rather than having to use the `Get Attributes` block.